# Curl echo only prints when code ends

Tags: php, curl

Good day,

I am trying to run a php script on cmd using curl (I have installed the windows version of curl). The thing is, all my echo calls print..but only after the script has ended. There is a while loop inside the script and I need to track what it's printing. Is there anyway I can get it to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP status code is something along the lines of:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://www.example.org/
```

A lot easier to work with in scripts, as it doesn't require any parsing :-)

The parameter `-I` might be added to improve response load performance. This parameter just request for status/headers of response, without download response body. (%{http_code} returns on first line of HTTP payload)

i.e.:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "%{http_code}" http://www.example.org/
```